# Redirecting constantly updating output

Tags: bash, redirect

This crazy bash invocation supposed to masseur downlink speed with respect to my ISP specific server.
Problem occurs when piping output of pv to sed. Instead of the last result form pv sed precessed the first one. Is it normal behavior when piping constantly updating output ?

```
for ((i=0;i<1;i++)) ; do
    echo DOWNLOAD $((2**30))  | nc ipv4.upcspeedtest.pl 10200
done | 
pv -f -a 2> >(tee >(cat >&2)) 1> /dev/null | 
sed -r 's|\[ *([0-9]+).*|scale=3;print \1, "KiB/s\n", \1*8/1024, "Mib/s\n"|g' |
bc -l
```

PS. To make this work I simply increase interval of pv to 300 seconds.

Comment: sed should process all the output from pv (assuming it is line based) are you sure that isn't happening? Have you waited to see what happens when it all finishes (the pipes/etc. are likely buffering input and output).

Comment: @EtanReisner sed have problem with carrier return produced by pv.

Comment: Ok. I figured this out.
When pipe `pv -a` to `sed '/s/\r/ /g'` output looks like this
`[ 579kiB/s] [ 486kiB/s] [ 439kiB/s] ...`
pv produce \r separated list of records.
When pipe pv to `sed -r 's|\[ *([0-9]+).*|\1|g'` sed takes the first mach omitting rest output produced by pv.
Everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured this out. When pipe `pv -a` to `sed '/s/\r/ /g'` output looks like this `[ 579kiB/s] [ 486kiB/s] [ 439kiB/s] ...` pv produce \r separated list of records. When pipe pv to `sed -r 's|[ ([0-9]+).|\1|g'` sed takes the first mach omitting rest output produced by pv. Everything is working as expected.
                    – Bartłomiej Szczepaniak